# cakePHP : retrieving the added year on edit

Tags: date, cakephp, edit, date-format

I want to retrieve the added year, for example 2012 when editing a form in cakePHP. But I always get the year 1970.

add and edit view code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('date_year', array(
   'label' => 'Year',
   'placeholder' => 'Year',
   'type' => 'date',
   'dateFormat' => 'Y',
   'minYear' => date('Y')-100, 
   'maxYear' => date('Y')-0+1, 
   'empty' => '- select -',
   'value' => date('Y'),
   'name' => 'data[Date][date_year]',
   'selected' => 'data[Date][date_year]'
));
```

My date_year field has the type year(4).

Generated HTML :

```
<label for="DateDateYearYear">Year</label>
<select name="data[Date][date_year]" class="form-control" placeholder="Year" id="DateDateYearYear" required="required">
   <option value="">- select -</option>
   <option value="2015">2015</option>
   <option value="2014">2014</option>
   ...
   <option value="1971">1971</option>
   <option value="1970" selected="selected">1970</option>
   <option value="1969">1969</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Comment: Paste at least some of the generated HTML for the input?  Also, what do you mean "I always get 1970" - where is the code in which you're retrieving the submitted value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `'selected' => 'data[Date][date_year]'` and now it works. I updated my question.